# iterate over two list simultaneously in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have 2 list (can be another data type also) that represent 2 vector clocks. How can I iterate over the two list simultaneously and verified this condition:  w[k] <= v[k] for each k != j, where j is a parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `Enum.zip/2`:

```
def check(w, v, j) do
  Enum.zip(w, v)
  |> Enum.with_index
  |> Enum.all?(fn {{ww, vv}, k} -> k == j || ww <= vv end)
end
```